# AWS. Как можно контролировать доступ к s3 bucket из lambda?

Tags: lambda, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

В AWS есть большое количество бакетов, к которым имеют доступ разные пользователи. И есть lambda функция, которая выбирает данные из s3 и отдает клиенту через Api Gateway. У клиента есть возможность указать в запросе к api из какого именно бакета lambda должна делать выборку. Но как проконтролировать, что он запрашивает именно тот бакет, к которому у него есть разрешение?

В политиках iam я могу лишь указать, что он может обращаться к конкретному api ресурсу, но ресурс общий для всех. В lambda authorizer я не могу получить информацию о правах и разрешениях пользователя (или могу?).

Пожалуйста, подскажите как можно решить этот вопрос. В какую сторону двигаться?

P.S. Это должна быть авторизация пользователей в amazon, я не могу выдавать им свои JWT со своими данными.

Answer (score 0):

Перечитал вопрос и осознал, что я его неверно понял.

1. Для начала надо убедиться, что только ламбда может читать. Иначе будут читать в обход твоего АПИ
2. "В lambda authorizer я не могу получить информацию о правах и разрешениях пользователя (или могу?)." - по АРН можно увидеть, пришёл он как юзер или как роль и сделать запрос в IAM чтобы прочитать principal policy. Вопрос только что ты собираешься хранить в policy, если пункт 1 правильно реализован. Лучше хранить в каком-нибудь Dynamo или S3, проверять в ауторайзере и выдавать результат проверки АПИ гейтвэю

Comment: я бы вообще поставил под вопрос саму идею - если ты что то читаешь для юзеров, зачем им вообще знать, откуда ты читаешь? Если им какие то бакеты доступны, пусть сами читают тогда или надо писать софт, который будет от их имени читать сразу и делать политику контроля через IAM.

Comment: @tym32167 Согласен, детали юзерам лучше не выдавать.

Comment: а как сами юзеры авторизируются? Если  AWS Cognito, то есть вариант. В противном случае нужно пересмотреть саму идею, как сказал @tym32167